# Scrollbar and resizing won't work with tkinter grid array and treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have written and application frontend with tkinter that uses a page manager layout and would like to lay it out with a grid system instead of pack. I could not get the scrollbar function to work at all with the grid layout so I set it up with pack. This generally works, but the layout I want will require a grid (or a bunch of extra frames while using pack).

Can someone take a look to see what I'm not getting? I have included code using the pack system that gives something close to what I want to achieve with grid. The corresponding grid commands that I thought would work are commented out.

I also took out the page management in the main class and reduced it to one page to make the issues more clear. I want to keep page management in the long run...

Thanks for looking!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

colHeadings = ['car', 'repair']
itemList = [('Hyundai', 'brakes'),('Honda', 'light'), 
            ('Lexus', 'battery'), ('Benz', 'wiper'), 
            ('Ford', 'tire'), ('Chevy', 'air'), 
            ('Chrysler', 'piston'), ('Toyota', 'brake pedal'), 
            ('BMW', 'seat')]

def buildtree(thetree, colHeadings, itemList):
    thetree['columns'] = colHeadings
    for each in colHeadings:
        thetree.column(each, width=tkFont.Font().measure(each.title()))
        thetree.heading(each, text=each.title())
    for item in itemList:
        thetree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
        for i, each in enumerate(item):
            colwidth = int(1.3*tkFont.Font().measure(each))
            if thetree.column(colHeadings[i], width=None) < colwidth:
                thetree.column(colHeadings[i], width=colwidth)

class AppBT(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        frame = StatsTree(container)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=1)
        frame.pack(side="top", fill="y",expand=1)
        # container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        # container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")


class StatsTree(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        tframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(tframe, orient="vertical")
        tree = ttk.Treeview(tframe)

        yscrollbar.config(command=tree.yview)
        tree.config(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

        buildtree(tree, colHeadings, itemList)

        tree.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        yscrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        tframe.pack(side="top", fill="y", expand=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        # tframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns", padx=10, pady=10)
        # tframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # tframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
        # tree.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # tree.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        # yscrollbar.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # yscrollbar.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


app = AppBT()
app.geometry("800x600")
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there's nothing wrong with how the scrollbars work. If you are able to shrink the window so that some of the items are obscured, the scrollbars will work as expected. There is nothing you need to do to fix the scrollbar behavior.

As a general rule of thumb, whenever you place widgets into another widget using `grid`, you must give at least one row and one column of the parent widget a positive weight. You are forgetting to do that in two places.

The first problem is that you're using `grid` to place `container` in the root window, but you haven't given a weight to the rows and columns in the root window. Therefore, `container` will not expand to fill the window as a whole, so nothing in `container` can expand, either.

Since this is the only widget in the root window, in my opinion it's a bit easier to use pack. Since you want to use grid you need to add the following in `AppBT.__init__`:

```
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

You repeat the same problem with `StatsTree` - you are using `grid` to place `tframe` in this frame, but you aren't configuring the weight of the rows and columns in `StatsTree`. That prevents `tframe` from expanding, which in turn prevents the tree and scrollbar from expanding.

You need to add the following to `StatsTree.__init__` if you wish to use grid for the child widgets in `StatsTree`

```
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1
```